# Edit Windows local group policy using vb.net instead of gpedit.msc

Tags: vb.net

Please I need some way to edit into Windows local group policy instead of manually using gpedit.msc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does _any_ search engine provide you of information?

Comment: I did not find any useful info. so I came here

Comment: 5 seconds searching gave me following interesting links: [**MSDN Group Policy Management Console Class Library**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee840126.aspx) and [**this blog post**](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2013/03/25/programmatically-updating-local-policy-in-windows). All with keywords from your post.

Comment: @Styxxy, It looks like the GPMC is explicitly designed for AD GPO's and/or doesn't support modifying GPO values,  and the process for tracking registry values doesn't seem to apply to many of the Local GP's that can be modified in the gpedit.msc interface (procmon shows no registry changes while making the change). Example: 2012SP1: "Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Perform volume maintenance tasks" add/remove SID to the list. 
If you or anyone can provide some assistance that would be extremely helpful!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry Styxxy, I'm searching for solution not to make another complication